# Adj. au pluriel avec « de »

Tags: grammaire, usage, adjectifs

La plupart du temps, je vois des phrases construites avec « de » + « adj. au pluriel » + « nom au pluriel » :

> *Comme j’ai cueilli **de** belles fleurs.*

Mais je lis :

> *Lancez-vous pour saisir **les** bonnes opportunités.*

Pourquoi est-ce que celle-ci utilise « les » ?

Comment: Le contexte est important. _J’ai cueilli **de** belles fleurs._ Il y a beaucoup de belles fleurs, j'ai cueilli quelques-unes parmi tout l'ensemble des belles fleurs, elles ne sont pas précises. Par contre, _saisir **les** bonnes opportunités_, c'est plus précis, on saisit toutes les bonnes opportunités, on ne fait pas le tri, on ne rejette aucune bonne opportunité.